# Why AutoConfigurationPackages not consider @ComponentScan?

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot's support for Spring data configuration is generally by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport`, and this class use the follow code to determine what packages to scan for repositories:

```
AutoConfigurationPackages.get(this.beanFactory)
```

So, basically Spring Data with Spring Boot only scan the package which contains the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` or `@ImportAutoConfiguration`, but not consider the `@ComponentScan`, Is this correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@ComponentScan` annotation is a core Spring Framework feature to search for classes annotated with `@Component`. Since Spring Data repositories are interfaces (and not annotated), the `@ComponentScan` annotation won't pick them up.

If you are using Spring Data outside of Spring Boot, you can scan for Spring Data repositories using `@EnableJpaRepositories` with the `basePackages` attribute set.

When it comes to Spring Boot, there's usually no need to use either `@ComponentScan` or `@EnableJpaRepositories`. If you [structure your code as suggested](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code), both components and repositories will be picked up.

To get back to your original question about `AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport`. If you look at the source of `@SpringBootApplication` you'll see it's annotated with `@ComponentScan` (to find `@Components`) and `@AutoConfigurationPackage` (via `@EnableAutoConfiguration`). The `@AutoConfigurationPackage` sets up `AutoConfigurationPackages` with the value that's later retrieved.

If you want to override the packages the Spring Data searches for repositories (for example in tests) you'll need to use `@EnableJpaRepositories` to completely override auto-configuration. I usually don't do this, but instead use `@DataJpaTest` and pick up my main configuration.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I have realized that I can use ```@AutoConfigurationPackage``` to specify the packages to use for repositories